# How does Sentry's semantic versioning work?

Tags: sentry, semantic-versioning

I’ve just done a new release to our customer and manually uploaded the version with:

```
sentry-cli releases new -p myproject 0.0.53
sentry-cli releases --org mycompany deploys 0.0.53 new -e beta
```

0.0.53 shows up in the Releases list. It’s top of the list of releases sorted by Semantic Versioning. But the list sorted by Build Number shows “There are no releases
with semantic versioning”:
https://sentry.io/organizations/mycompany/releases/?sort=build

If “0.0.53” isn’t semantic versioning then what is?

Update:

I'm confused because although in [Bind The Version](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/configuration/releases/#bind-the-version) they give the example `my.project.name@2.3.12+1234` elsewhere they mention using [semver 2.0.0](https://semver.org/) - this accepts a version MAJOR.MINOR.BUILD with no brackets. Also in [Passing Additional Data](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/guides/minidumps/#minidump-additional) the version is shown as "2.3.12" which is the same format as what we're providing now.

Answer (score 1):

From their documentation on release, it looks like they are expecting a value comprised of package name, version  number, and build number, like so -

`my.project.name@2.3.12+1234`

More details here - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/releases/#bind-the-version

Comment: I've updated the question - they seem to be inconsistent in their documentation.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, and the documentation was probably misleading in the past. In [Passing additional data](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/guides/minidumps/#minidump-additional) they also use "my-project-name@2.3.12" now.